# Migrating from PlusClient to GoogleApiClient in Android Studio using refactor tool

Tags: android, android-studio, google-plus, google-api-client

As is public knowledge, Google has replaced the `PlusClient` API with the `GoogleApiClient` API and advises that all code using the old API should be migrated  to the new one. I used the New Activity option in Android Studio to create a LoginActivity, but this uses the old API.
Besides downgrading the version of Google play services to accommodate this old API, everything works just fine(?). But I want to migrate to the new API for all the obvious reasons.

So, I used `Refactor | Migrate`

and got here ( I added the migration map myself):

[image]

[image]

filled in all the values and clicked `Ok`

I am the presented with this:

[image]

What I make of this is that Android studio found the instances of PlusClient usage in my code and is ready to replace them. When I click on `Do Refactor` however, nothing else really happens other than this:

```
 mPlusClient =
            new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                    Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
```

being replaced with this:

```
 mPlusClient = new com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
    .Builder(this, this, this)
    .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                    Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
```

With errors.

Is this the proper way to do the migration? Or do I face reality and do it in code?

Answer (score 1):

The Migrate tool in Android Studio does exactly that: when an API you're using is moved to a different package, it can replace the calls in your code so that they also use the new package. It does not perform any other changes to your code.

It would be wonderful indeed if you could enter any two classes and Android Studio could magically figure out all the changes to your code that would be required to use one class instead of the other, but unfortunately this isn't really possible with today's technology.